# HOWTO: Know which records were restored into a SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, database-backups, database-restore

I have two databases in different servers. For example, db_A in server_A and db_B in server_B.

A few weeks ago I did a full backup to disk of db_A using SSME through "Tasks-Back Up..." option and then selecting "Full" as backup type. The backup completed successfully without errors. Afterwards, I restored the backup into db_B in server_B through "Tasks->Restore->Database..." and then selecting as source the bak file and finally selecting restoring options "WITH REPLACE" and "RESTORE WITH RECOVERY" as recovery state. The restore process completed successfully as well.

Recently some guys has told me that some concrete tables have missing data.

So I am trying to know what has happened. As far as I know if backup and restore processes completes successfully, in "theory" it means all data have been restored successfully into tables.

Hence that I think two situations may be happen:

1. Data in those tables was not there in the moment I did the backup.
2. Someone deleted the data from that tables after restoring database.

So I would like to know if there is any way to know which data was restored and inserted into those tables and whether table records were deleted after restoring process. Is there any T-SQL command to know that?

Comment: I can absolutely guarantee that the restore did not miss any records that were actually in your backup. So that's a starting point. Why don't you restore the data into a new database and do a compare?

Comment: I agree with @TomC. You may have inadvertently appended to an existing backup file ( a backup file can contain multiple backups). The first (oldest) is restored by default.

Comment: @TomC I cannot do it because once restored the backup file was deleted due to disk space in server...

Comment: @DanGuzman if that was the case, in some place when restoring it should have indicated the files the backup file contains (with the oldest select by default), or not? When backing up I left all the options by default, so appended but it was the first time I made the backup... If I remeber well no other backup were done previously. In the table shown at the bottom of the restore window there was only 1 backup file and it was checked by default indicating the date. Date was the most recent.

Comment: How important is it to you. From what you are saying I get the idea that backups are few and far between. If that's the case then a record of everything you did will be in the logs. There are tools out there that will let you read a log file, I've never used one but googling might help. There are also some articles about doing it manually. I've never done any of this, but hope that's a starting point.

Comment: @user1624552, I personally use T-SQL rather than the SSMS wizards for backup and restores rather than let SSMS predict my intentions. If what you remember is true, then the data was no present in the database when the backup was taken or was deleted afterwards. Run another restore to a different database name to identify which is the case in your situation.